# Array not showing matches from imploded result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm getting an array of record IDs, 1000 to be exact, and it's returning properly. IN order to bind them to another result set, I'm imploding them and when I print the implode variable, it is printing a question mark for each ID that is returned:

```
$openArray = [];
while($openRow = $openOrders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $openArray[] = $openRow['order_id'];
}

$openOrderIDs = implode(',',$openArray);

print_r($openArray); //This prints the proper array of 1000 ids
```

Up to this point I'm getting what I expect. This next portion is basically selecting from another database table where a field matches on the imploded `$placeHolder` array

```
$getMatches = "
    SELECT 
         orderC as order
     FROM orders
     WHERE orderC IN ($openOrderIDs)
     AND status = 'S'
";

try{
        $openMatches = $DB2conn->prepare($getMatches);
        $matchResult = $openMatches->execute($openOrderIDs);
    }catch(PDOException $ex){
        echo "QUERY FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
    }

$matchArray=[];
while ($matchRow = $openMatches->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $matchArray[] = $matchRow['order'];
}

print_r($matchArray);
```

So basically, of the 1000 returned IDs, I want to perform my next SELECT `WHERE orderc matches ID in placeholders`.

I should have 1000 matches but I have none right now and I think it's because I"m not binding properly from placeholders. The problem is I don't get an error either, just an empty array/result.

Am I just totally missing something?

Comment: do you have made a var_dump($placeholders) to seen what they are in this variable before the $getMatches ?

Comment: `orderC as order` vs `$matchRow['invnoc']` could be part of it.

Comment: @PatrickQ I fixed that in the code above just now, but no it matches in my code and still the same

Comment: you are not storing comma seperated values in  columns by any chance are you>

Comment: @Inazo yes it prints a question mark for each value in the previous array

Comment: @e4c5 no the columns are just IDs, no comma separated values

Comment: So you're saying that this isn't a copy/paste of your actual code? And what you have is still wrong. You're aliasing `orderC as order`.  That means you need to access it as `$matchRow['order']`.  And what exactly are you expecting `$matchCount = $openMatches->fetch();` to do?

Comment: It is a copy paste I just didn't update my values from the test table. I fixed locally and forgot to fix it here. As far as your last question, I had originally put that in the try loop to do a fetch and then ended up doing the while loop at the bottom but I kept it for reference

Comment: @PatrickQ I'm wondering if I'm passing my placeholders in properly though

Comment: Implode `$openArray` and use the result instead of the placeholders.  That will tell you.  If you know for sure that these are integers, then there's really not much benefit to using bound parameters anyway.

Comment: @PatrickQ I see, I've tried that as shown in my edit above but I can't execute on the string from the implode. Now that I've imploded and used that result in the query, should I change how I execute for $matchResult?

Comment: Yes, it would just be `$openMatches->execute();`

Comment: Got it now, thanks!